# Error render with BootstrapTable in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I'm using BootstrapTable with React JS to show my data that I'm getting with a Graphql query.
But when trying to do the render, it shows me the following error

```
 TypeError: _this.props.data.slice is not a function at new BootstrapTable
```

I'm doing it like this:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props
        const { loading, payment } = data

        if (loading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        if (payment.client) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <BootstrapTable data={payment.client}>
                    { console.log("==============================>", data.payment.client) }   
                        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField={true}>  id           
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField={data.payment.client.name}>  name 
                     </BootstrapTable>
                </div>
            )
         }
         return <div> Nothing... </div>
    }

 }
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: that means table is not getting the data array, do one thing `console.log('data', payment.client)` inside `if(payment.client)` and check whether it have proper array or not.

Comment: can you check the typeOf the prop "data"

Comment: @ShashithDarshana  `{ console.log( "=====>",typeof(payment.client)) }` return a `object`, aslo with `data`

Comment: can you post the log out put(to see the structure of the object) seems like you are giving an object to bootstraptable where it requires an array

Comment: `  {
    payment_id: 2, 
    amount: 7, 
    client_id: 11,
    client:{
        name: "Jon", 
        last_name: "Soto...", 
        rfc: "FSAS..."
    …}
  }` My object